# Phaser 3 spritesheet not displaying on iOS - Shows black rectangle instead

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework, capacitor

I have a project built with phaser 3, and strangely it doesn't show the spritesheet (it appears as black rectangle instead). It only happens in mobile (running on simulator and running on mobile safari). On my mac, it displays properly (both chrome and safari).

Code:

In `boot-scene.ts`:

```
this.load.spritesheet('character-walk', 'assets/walk.png',
    { frameWidth: 547, frameHeight: 481 },
);
```

In `game-scene.ts`:

```
this.player = this.add.sprite(100, 600, 'character-walk')
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type: Phaser.CANVAS` is not a solution if the project requires WebGL acceleration.  I am finding that this happens when the sprite is over a certain number of pixels in any one direction.  For instance, I have a 3000px x 6000px sprite sheet image exhibiting this behavior but when it is cut to 3000px x 3000px it loads as expected on iOS.

Comment: oh, yeah, it seems the size of the image makes difference

Comment: Resizing below 3000 pixels fixed the issue for me. I switch between sprites when booting depending on the width of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be downloaded properly. Where do you serve this spritesheet from? Does this server allows requests from the origin you make the request from (i.e. your app's origin)?

If not, you may need to allow CORS in your server.

Comment: It was a strange bug, setting `type: Phaser.CANVAS` in gameConfig fixed this issue. It seems `type:Phaser.AUTO` makes it not render sprites on iOS.

Comment: It can still be the issue how the request is done based on this config you have mentioned. For example with auto one of the systems you use may be selecting webgl and the library you use may be requesting the resources in a way your server is not responding well, that is rejecting to serve, and canvas config may be resulting in cross origin allowed situation. Glad to see you have fixed your problem, but I do not see a definitive answer has been presented so far for the problem at hand, we do not know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

setting `type: Phaser.CANVAS` in gameConfig fixed this issue. It seems `type:Phaser.AUTO` makes it not render sprites on iOS.